# Silly question about Schwarzschild Solution

Tags: general-relativity, curvature, vacuum

**The following question is based upon elementary concepts of General Relativity, and Tensor Calculus**

The condition for a space-time manifold to be flat is:

$$R^{a}_{bcd} \equiv 0 $$

I.e., the Riemann Tensor is must be identically null.

And, Einstein Field Equations are written in terms of Ricci tensor ($R_{bd} = R^{a}_{bad}$) as follows:

\begin{equation}
\tag{1}
R_{bd} - \frac{1}{2}Rg_{bd} = 8\pi T_{bd}
\end{equation}

My question is: If a vaccum solutions of (1) is the one that:
\begin{equation}
  \tag{2}
  R_{bd} = 0
\end{equation}

And, since Ricci tensor is just a contraction of Riemann tensor, vaccum solutions describe a flat or curved manifold? Ok, I know that (2) gathers both kinds of solutions (even still confused), but what is the whole of Energy-Momentum tensor and Vaccum Solutions then?(e.g. what happens if I put Dust Energy-Momentum tensor on Schwarzschild metric. I mean if Schwarzschild solution is derived from (2) what suppose to mean a solution with Energy-momentum tensor?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, ${R^a}_{bcd} = 0$ does imply that $R_{bd} = 0$, but $R_{bd} = 0$ does not imply that ${R^a}_{bcd} = 0$.

Also, in General Relativity specifically, we're not usually too interested in metrics that satisfy ${R^a}_{bcd} = 0$.  These are called Riemann-flat metrics.  Some important geometric objects are Riemann-flat, but they don't generally make the most interesting model spacetime.

Now, if you know that your spacetime has stress-energy tensor $T_{bd}$ that is *not* equal to zero, but the metric of the spacetime is exactly Schwarzschild, then you don't have a solution of Einstein's equations.  Maybe it's *almost* a solution, or maybe it's a solution to some modified form of gravity, but it just doesn't satisfy your equation (1).  That's all that says.  It's still a geometrically possible manifold, it just doesn't correspond to what we believe is physical reality.

On the other hand, if you know that your spacetime has stress-energy tensor $T_{bd}$ that is not equal to zero *and* you know that your spacetime satisfies Einstein's equations, then you know that your metric is not the same as Schwarzschild — you need to look for some other metric to satisfy equation (1).

Comment: what are " important geomeric objects which are Riemann flat"? I only see one, minkowski space time

Comment: The Riemann tensor is not only used for spacetimes in GR; it can also be computed for other manifolds. The line, the plane, the circle, and many other geometrical objects can be endowed with a flat metric. But as I said, Riemann-flat manifolds do not make for interesting model spacetimes in GR.  Of course, this is not to mention Minkowski with non-trivial topological identifications, which is a non-trivial object of study for some relativists.